# What are some popular theories/opinions in philosophy against the certainty placed on the laws of logic and its results?

Tags: logic, metaphysics

What are some popular theories/opinions in philosophy against the certainty placed on the laws of logic and its results?

You would think philosophers wouldn't ever criticize or try to debunk logic or any part thereof, considering philosophers deals with logical ideas; but you would at least think that there were some doubts, theories and ideas that were advanced that put some doubts to the foundation of logic, parts thereof, and results derived from it.

Can you think of any such theories/opinions?

Comment: Most philosophical ideas are not "logical", and philosophers criticize existing logics and develop new ones all the time since Aristotle, you'll have to be more specific. See e.g. [SEP The One Right Logic?](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/logic-classical/#Right) on the modern criticisms of classical logic.

Comment: Logic is not my “specialty” but you may like this book “Walking the Tightrope of Reason” Robert Fogelin. https://www.amazon.com/Walking-Tightrope-Reason-Robert-Fogelin/dp/0195160266/ref=mp_s_a_1_2?keywords=fogelin&qid=1566350973&s=books&sr=1-2

Comment: All logic is constrained by time, space, and causation; it is limited to the empirical world. Buddhistic and Vedantic philosophy recognizes that all logic is eventually circular and self-referential.

Comment: It seems to me philosophers debunk logical results as a matter of course. Most endorse views that fail in logic then blame logic for being useless. It's an odd business. It leads to the view that metaphysics is useless, a view that depends entirely on rejecting ordinary logic.  . .

Comment: @PeterJ "It leads to the view that metaphysics is useless, a view that depends entirely on rejecting ordinary logic" What? How does dismissing metaphysics entail dismissing ordinary logic? (Also, what precisely is "ordinary logic"?)

Comment: @PeterJ  Being told absolutely false things about myself is already a silly insult.  If you want a civil conversation, conduct one.\

Comment: @Jobermark - This comment confuses me. Did I tell you something false about yourself? I hope I didn't say anything false at any time, or that was my intention. I understand that you're enraged by by what you see as my dogmatic over-confident because you believe it is not possible to be confident. You must assume I am an arrogant fool. I'm well used to this assumption. The problem is that it depends on an assumption about philosophy and knowledge you do not know is true. Let's pause here. I'm going to ask a question  addressing more directly the topics we're discussing here. .

Comment: @PeterJ  I don't know a single philosopher writing today would would claim logic is 'useless'.  And I have not 'abandoned logic' myself.  These are false statements.  When I enumerate contradictions to your direct statements, you act like I am a moron who cannot read.  This is not about 'confidence' or any assumptions.  It is about the factual difference between what people do and say and what you keep telling us they/we do and say.  You seem to have your own definition of logic that is different from the one everyone else here is using.  We *may* find what you want to label logic as useless.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are various paradoxes of logic that indicate to a certain degree that it is not entirely certain.  The one of these that has gotten the widest coverage is Russel's paradox that demonstrated the naive notion of containment has a flaw, and cannot be arbitrarily combined with both negation and universal quantification.  "Does the set of all things that do not have themselves as elements have itself as an element?"

This relatively simple question precipitated a deep concern within the Philosophy of Mathematics, which given our modern take on logic as a part of mathematics, is the same field that would cover the certainty of logic.  The primary reactions were basically:

1) Mathematical Platonism: ignore the problem and assume paradoxes are simply so strange in form we remain safe, because no important argument will be nearly that strange.  The approaches within this range argue about why this should be the case, about how the paradoxes are or are not 'real enough' and ultimately about different theories of idealism and realism in general.

2) Type Theory: be suspicious of self-reference and referential loops in general and assume the rest of logic is safe.  This flows into thinking about recursive function theory, proof theory and category theory, which have their own ways of looking at ordered or simultaneous circular references, and more casual theories like Douglas Hoffstadter's notions of the 'strange loop'.

3) Constructivism or Intuitionism: insist all statements of existence rely upon finite extensions of arguments about finite things (ruling out the idea that infinite or ambiguous things are either true or false.)  The different approaches here disagree on what it means for an extension of an argument to be finite.

4) Formalism or Fictionalism: deny that the objects reckoned about are real in any important sense and stick with finite syntactical transformations as ways to preserve truth, excluding the problematical ones as we encounter them.  (So in this case, we propose a set of syntactical rules that identify what sets it is safe to discuss.  If we really *need* to discuss more general things, we will add more rules.)  The different approaches disagree on whether how we treat the cases we are ruling out -- are they false? are they ambiguous? do we need a hierarchy of models that covers each possible case (a la Woodin's investigations)? or should we just remain open to encountering them as we go along.

There is a lot of discussion about the positive and negative aspects of these theories starting from Russel's era and intensifying through the mid 1970's, when a resurgence of ancient observations about definitions and language resurrected by Quine and the postmodernists reduced the relevance of foundational arguments.

All of these remain interesting theories.  (Even the first one.)  And the gaps between them are far from resolved.

And the paradox that precipitated all of this is not among the most interesting to many people.  These approaches and variants on them may also consider the Barry Paradox, Curry's Paradox, Zeno's paradoxes of continuity and the related Banach-Tarski paradoxes of space and measure, paradoxes of instantaneous ambiguity and symmetry in physics related to the ancient 'ass' and 'sorites' problems, and many others.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me philosophers debunk logical results as a matter of course. Most endorse views that fail in logic then blame logic for being useless. It's an odd business. It leads to the view that metaphysics is useless, a view that depends entirely on rejecting ordinary logic.

So, examples of views that assume classical logic is flawed are all the views held by philosophers who endorse theories that do not work in metaphysics, which is all but one of them.

Few philosophers bother with classical logic. If they have a view they like they tend to ignore the fact it fails in logic. They would rather assume classical logic is flawed. Examples of theories that assume this logic is flawed are all theories that fail under analysis, which is all theories promoted and examined in academic metaphysics.

*What are some popular theories/opinions in philosophy against the certainty placed on the laws of logic and its results?*

The most popular theory/opinion states that the failure in logic of all positive metaphysical theories is due to a flaw in logic and is not a proof of their falsity. This view is so ubiquitous that we could generalise and say that in Russell's 'Western' tradition nobody places any certainty in the laws of logic and its results. It's a condition of membership. The preferred view is that the logical results of metaphysics should be ignored and a new form of logic should be invented that allows us to hold on to our favourite views and theories.

This approach allows a thousand theories to flourish, which is fun, but it reduces philosophy to a hopeless muddle.

Comment: "all but one of them" That one being ...? And, can you give any examples of or evidence for these rather sweeping claims?

Comment: 'not complete and perfect in every way' does not equal  'useless'

Comment: @NoahSchweber - Only one theory is correct, so only one works in logic. My evidence would be the history of philosophy, during which nobody has found a second theory that works. For a single source I'd cite either Nagarjuna's 'Fundamental Wisdom of the Middle Way', Brown's 'Laws of Form' or Bradley's 'Appearance and Reality'.

Comment: @jobermark - Okay. No argument from me.

Comment: This is entirely opinion, it is not clear what philosophers or schools of philosophy you are talking about, but what you are saying is not true of most of them, which is what you claim.  As noted, you claim most philosophers label classical logic useless when they are fascinated with its flaws, but really they are often really just amazed either that there are any flaws there at all, or that we can function as well as we do given that there are any flaws in so basic a necessary part of our thinking.  (explaining my downvote)

Comment: Go look at a list of the top N philosophers some time, a lot of them starting from Lewis, Searle, Nagel, Chalmers... are basically logical positivists ignoring the basic flaws in logic as irrelevant.  The opposing POV gets a lot of coverage exactly because it is so hard to follow, so people raise questions or objections in trying to puzzle it out.

Comment: @jobermark - You say 'a lot of them starting from Lewis, Searle, Nagel, Chalmers... are basically logical positivists ignoring the basic flaws in logic as irrelevant.' What basic flaws? These folk become logical positivists rather than trust their own logical results and this is exactly the point I was making. Please don't think I'm just waiving my opinions around. Logical positivism  is the rejection of logic and metaphysics for the idea that logic is flawed or the universe is paradoxical.

Comment: The result being that philosophy is reduced to a hopeless muddle.

Comment: @PeterJ  They remain counterexamples to your statements.  Statements with numerous counterexamples are wrong.  You are wrong.  They do not consider logic useless, they use it extensively with great faith -- contrary to your condescending dismissal of the whole lot of them/

Comment: @PeterJ  The downvote is deserved because the answer is just calumny and contains no real information.  If you ASK ME why i did something and I TELL YOU, you should LISTEN.  Otherwise stop lying and saying you would like the information.

Comment: @jobermark - I feel the problem would be solved if you took the trouble to read what I said carefully and found substantial fault with it instead of just reacting like I've personally offended you. The philosophers mentioned reject the results of logic, thus rejecting logic. If they did not do this they'd have no reason to argue that logic is flawed.

Comment: @PeterJ  That is nonsense.  Logic is flawed because paradoxes exist.  Period.  That is not something philosophers invented to escape responsibilty.  It was equally obvious throughout antiquity when most of those paradoxes were discovered, and those folks surely were not of the opinion that metaphysics was useless -- they kind of invented it.  There is no logical connection here, just baseless blame.

Comment: @jobermark - What paradoxes? I know of none. We should move to 'chat' if you want to continue. . .

Comment: @PeterJ I do not wish to be ignored pointedly in a more efficient environment.  There is nothing you are willing to hear me say.

Comment: Re: What paradoxes.  Read my answer.